# обращение к полям структуры через указатель

Tags: c++

Понятно, что в методе `void additem(int d)` мы можем обратиться к полям структуры `link` через указатель на объект структуры следующим образом:

```
newlink->data = d;
newlink->next = first;
```

**Тогда** каким образом мы обращаемся к этим самым полям структуры через указатель `current` в методе класса, если этот указатель не указывает на структуру с самого начала:

```
link* current = first;
    while (current)
    {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
```

**???**

Код:

```
class linklist
{
    struct link
    {
        int data;
        link* next;

    };

    link* first;
public:
    linklist() : first(NULL)
    { }
    void additem(int d);
    void display();
};

void linklist::additem(int d)
{
    link* newlink = new link;
    newlink->data = d;
    newlink->next = first;
    first = newlink;
}

void linklist::display()
{
    link* current = first;
    while (current)
    {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    linklist li;
    li.additem(23);
    li.additem(9);
    li.additem(11);
    li.additem(0);

    li.display();

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что значит "не указывает на структуру с самого начала" ? У Вас же указатель current внутри метода обращается к инициализированному в конструкторе first.

Comment: `current` - в вашем случае это `i` - переменная цикла. У вас цикл к следующему, пока следующий существует. Впринципе `for (i=0;i<n;i++)` можно записать как `i=0` (first)  `while (i< n) { i=i+1}` вместо `i=i+1` у вас `current =current->next;`

Comment: а как мы обращаемся к данным структуры через указатель `current`, если `current`- не указывает на объект структуры?

Comment: @Artem Aleksandrovich: Ваше утверждение "current не указывает на объект структуры" неверно. От того, что вы его будете повторять, верным оно не станет. Current у вас указывает на объект вашей структуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указатель *current* у Вас встречается внутри метода, а в метод, как известно, передается неявный указатель this на объект (если конечно это не статический метод).

Согласно приведенному коду, у вас получается список, в котором указатель *first* указывает на последний добавленный в список объект:

```
NULL <-- |el1.next| <-- |el2.next| <-- first
```

1. В случае, когда элементов нет, *display()* ничего не выведет, так как проверяется условие

   > while (current)
2. После того, как будет добавлен первый элемент, *first* указывает на этот элемент списка, а поле *next* элемента - на NULL. Соответственно, в функции *display()*, присваивая указателю *current* значение указателя *first*, Вы можете обращаться к полям структуры, которая является элементом списка.

UPD :

> а как мы обращаемся к данным структуры через указатель current, если
>   current- не указывает на объект структуры?

*current* внутри метода *display()* присваивается значение указателя *first*, который как раз **указывает на структуру** внутри класса *linklist*.